# how can I fix this urlString error from returning nil

Tags: json, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, httprequest

So my goal is to successfully send notifications to users subscribed to a specific topic with no errors. I have a function that I use to send notifications with FCM, here it is:

```
func sendNotificationToUser(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
    getTheSchoolID { (id) in
        if let id = id {
            let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/thenameofmyproject-41f12/messages:send HTTP/1.1"
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            let paramString: [String: Any] = ["message": ["topic": id,
                                                          "notification": ["title": title, "body": body],
                                                          "data": ["user": "test_id"]
                                              ]
            ]
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("Bearer \(self.bearer)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let jsonData = data {
                        if let jsonDataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDictionary))")
                        }
                    }
                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(err.debugDescription)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        
    }

}
```

I found this block of code originally off a Youtube video and tested it with my iPhone and it worked beautifully, but I modified it a bit to look like this and now when this function gets ran I get an error saying the `urlString` is producing a nil value.

[image: error]

I copied the format from the documentation and just switched out the project name, but for some reason I still get errors. Is there something wrong with url that I can't see? Also, in the image I shown below, should I add the "`ya29.`" before my bearer key or is the value just fine how it is?
[image: image from firebase docs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do, you dont trigger notifications by calling APNS/fcm API directly from client apps, anyway question is why is `URL` is being nil, well you can avoid it being nil if you percentile encode the url string

```
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/thenameofmyproject-41f12/messages:send HTTP/1.1"
        guard let encodedURLString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) else { return }
        let url = URL(string: encodedURLString)! //NSURL(string: encodedURLString)!
```

You dont need `NSURL` you can use `URL` instead.

**Why percentile encode?**

Because your url has a white space between send and HTTP `send HTTP` and white spaces are not allowed in valid url, if you want that white space to persist in your URL you should encode it. White space will be replaced by %20